# Alterar texto do TextView em um Fragment Android

Tags: java, android

Tenho um `TextView` dentro de um `Fragment` (uma aba).
Como faço para alterar o texto deste `TextView`?
Aqui fica dando `NullPointer`

```
qtAllImagensLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.qtAllImagensLabel);

qtAllImagensLabel.setText("texto");
```

Já tentei inicializar o `TextView` dentro do `onCreateView()`, e já tentei alterar o texto dentro de um `Handler`.
Quando tento alterar dentro de um `Handler`, ele não altera, mas não da `NullPointer`

Edit:
Inicio as variáveis globalmente e no `onCreateView()` faço elas receberem o `findViewById()`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_umclique_tab, container, false);

        qtAllImagensLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.qtAllImagensLabel);
        qtAllVideosLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.qtAllVideosLabel);
        qtAllAudioLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.qtAllAudioLabel);

        return view;
}
```

Até ai tudo bem, mas tentei setar o texto dentro e fora do `onCreate()`, dentro de um `Button`, mas não da.

Erro:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.tupinikimtecnologia.whatsappmediahidder/br.com.tupinikimtecnologia.whatsappmediahidder.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2216)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5140)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at br.com.tupinikimtecnologia.whatsappmediahidder.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:103)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2170)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5140)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Se eu coloco dentro de um handler, ele não da erro, mas também não altera o texto.

Layout do fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relative1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/umclique_tab_descricao_label"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relative2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/umclique_tab_border">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/umclique_tab_titulo_imagem"
            android:id="@+id/imagensTituloLabel"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/umclique_tab_qt_imagem"
            android:id="@+id/visEsconderLabel1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imagensTituloLabel"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/umclique_tab_qt_all_label"
            android:id="@+id/qtAllImagensLabel"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/visEsconderLabel1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/visEsconderLabel1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/umclique_tab_botao_revelar"
            android:id="@+id/mostrarButton1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/visEsconderLabel1"
            style="@style/ButtonVerdeMostrar"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imagensTituloLabel"
            android:onClick="mostrarImagensUmCliqueTab" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/umclique_tab_botao_esconder"
            android:id="@+id/esconderButton1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/visEsconderLabel1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagensTituloLabel"
            style="@style/ButtonVermelhoEsconder"
            android:onClick="esconderImagensUmCliqueTab" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/umclique_tab_border">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/umclique_tab_botao_revelar"
            android:id="@+id/mostrarButton2"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/visEsconderLabel2"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView6"
            style="@style/ButtonVerdeMostrar"
            android:onClick="mostrarVideosUmCliqueTab" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/umclique_tab_titulo_video"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/umclique_tab_qt_video"
            android:id="@+id/visEsconderLabel2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/umclique_tab_qt_all_label"
            android:id="@+id/qtAllVideosLabel"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/visEsconderLabel2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/visEsconderLabel2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/umclique_tab_botao_esconder"
            android:id="@+id/esconderButton2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mostrarButton2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
            style="@style/ButtonVermelhoEsconder"
            android:onClick="esconderVideosUmCliqueTab" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/preto">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/umclique_tab_botao_revelar"
            android:id="@+id/mostrarButton3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/visEsconderLabel3"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView9"
            style="@style/ButtonVerdeMostrar" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/umclique_tab_titulo_audio"
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/umclique_tab_qt_audio"
            android:id="@+id/visEsconderLabel3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/umclique_tab_qt_all_label"
            android:id="@+id/qtAllAudioLabel"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/visEsconderLabel3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/visEsconderLabel3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/umclique_tab_botao_esconder"
            android:id="@+id/esconderButton3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/visEsconderLabel3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView9"
            style="@style/ButtonVermelhoEsconder" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Em geral para buscar um elemento do layout de um `Fragment` é feito o `findViewById` na `View` que foi inflada pelo `LayoutInflater` dentro do `onCreateView` e logo depois retornada como resultado. Se esta fazendo isso, poste o código e o layout desse `Fragment`.

Comment: Já editei @Wakim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Está havendo um engano nesse código, esta se referindo ao `Fragment` mas esse código esta sendo executado numa `Activity` correto? Digo isso porque só a classe `Activity` (tirando as `Views`) possui o método `findViewById`, na [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) da classe `Fragment` não possui esse método.

O problema que está encontrando é por questão de ciclo de vida, o método `onCreateView` na `Activity` é chamado para inflar o `layout` da `Activity`, que por sua vez se estiver com a declaração de tag `<fragment>` correta, ira iniciar o `Fragment` chamando seu `onCreate` e posteriormente o `onCreateView`.

O ciclo seria algo como:

1. Activity.onCreate
2. Activity.onCreateView
3. Fragment.onAttach
4. Fragment.onCreate
5. Fragment.onCreateView

<sub>Mais detalhes em [Fragment LifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle)</sub>

E no momento em que faz `findViewById` por elementos do `Fragment` no método `onCreateView`, ele ainda não existe e não está construído. Por isso ele não encontra os elementos, e além disso, a *Root* `View` da `Activity` não foi construída por completo, apenas inflada. Logo não pode usar o `findViewById`, teria que usar `view.findViewById` para achar elementos desse layout e não do layout do `Fragment`.

Olhando esse layout, para usar `Fragment` teria que ter um layout para a `Activity` dessa forma (acredito que esteja usando assim certo?):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/id_do_fragment"
        android:name="pacote.da.classe.ClasseDoFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:tag="@string/tag_do_fragment" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Você usaria esse layout como sendo da `Activity` e dentro o layout do `Fragment` o que você colocou na pergunta.

Você terá que mudar a abordagem.

Nesse caso sugiro duas simples (**recomendo a primeira**):

1. Migrar essas referências para o `Fragment`, usando o método `onCreateView` do `Fragment` para as inicializar. O código ficaria muito parecido com o atual, salvo as mudanças de lógica que é recomendado, porque acaba delegando algumas responsabilidades para o `Fragment`. Tornando o código menos acoplado (se feito da maneira certa) e mais modularizável.
2. Ou usar o método `onViewCreated` do `Fragment` para notificar a `Activity` (usando Listener ou a própria referencia da `Activity`) de que a `View` foi contruída e é seguro acessá-la.

   No Fragment:

   ```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ((SuaActivity) getActivity()).onFragmentViewCreated(view); // Metodo que deve ser implementado na Activity
    }
   ```

   Na Activity:

   ```
    public void onFragmentViewCreated(View view) {
        // Iniciar os campos buscando no layout do Fragment
        qtAllImagensLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.qtAllImagensLabel);
        qtAllVideosLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.qtAllVideosLabel);
        qtAllAudioLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.qtAllAudioLabel);
    }
   ```

Comment: Com sua resposta percebi que eu estava usando a classe errada, agora está funcionando, deve ser horas sem beber café...